Momentarily or in a moment?
What is the correct phrase to indicate something is going to happen in a short while from now? Should we say "momentarily" or "in a moment"? Do both mean the same?
For example:

We will come back momentarily

vs

We will be back in a moment

I searched for a post related to this matter on this community but didn't find anything.

Welcome to ELL. What research have you done to find the answer for yourself? What has your research uncovered?

Please see momentarily. In BrE they don't mean the same thing.

In AmE they do mean the same thing.

@WeatherVane - let's not forget another one, 'presently', which also has different British (soon) and US (now) meanings.

The two sentences mean the same in the US but different in UK.  Momentarily means in a moment in the US but for a moment in the UK.
The OP should use the second sentence, which will be understood by both sides to mean in a short while.
Edit
We should use the clearer phrases
in (or for) a moment to talk about the two situations:
We'll be back in a moment.
We'll be back for a moment (or for a while).
Momentarily is more likely for usage like 'I waited momentarily before crossing the street' or
I touched the kettle momentarily to gauge the temperature.

In AmE we can say "I waited momentarily before crossing the street" or "I'll be there momentarily."

Thanks, @TimR.  So the first momentarily means for a moment, same as the UK meaning.

Don't overstate the US/UK difference. It's very unlikely anyone would use I will return momentarily to mean briefly, so we'd normally assume the more typically American sense of in a moment rather than for a moment. It's not like Brits are unaware of the two possible meanings, but I think we tend to favour in/for a moment for the avoidance of doubt anyway, unless being (facetiously) "stuffy / formal"..

Thanks,  @FumbleFingers.   I've edited my answer.
